# How change icon dataList of PrimeFaces Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

I have a question I have a problem to change the icon DataList Primeface Mobile.
I researched according to style: `<p class="ui-li-aside" />` brings the icon and position, I tried to create my own style and add the icon does not work me.

default.css (created style)

```
.ui-li-edit {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3.333em;
    text-align: right;
    top: 1em;

    background-image:
    url("/sgcc-web-app/javax.faces.resource/images/icons-18-white.png.jsf?ln=primefaces-mobile");
    background-position: -108px 70%;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a custom icon on the side you need to create a class and add into the `a` tag in the list items. You need to add the `:after` in the class to make it work. This method acts the same as `ui-li-aside` but with a custom icon.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/0596ezfo/

**CSS & HTML**

```
.ui-icon-myicon:after {
    background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Cute-Ball-Favorites-icon.png");
    /* Make your icon fit */
    background-size: 28px 28px;
}


<li><a class="ui-icon-myicon">MY Custom Icon</a></li>
```